# Capybara timing issue

Tags: rspec, capybara

Capybara intelligently waits to keep the sequence of test commands in sync with the UI. However, I've got a false positive from the following:

1. Fill in value to input field
2. Click link that incorrectly redirects to same page, wiping out previous value
3. Test checks value of the field. Since the redirect has not come back yet, the old value is still there, recording a false positive.

I was wondering if there is a way correctly test this case, **ensuring that incorrect case is caught**. Not surprisingly, when the code is fixed to use an ajax call, the test passes.

A more direct way to do the test would be to assert that the page did not redirect after clicking the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, when you click a regular link or button, Capybara should wait until the new page loaded. Perhaps something else is going wrong?

Comment: This definitely works in recent versions with phantomjs, EVEN with remote ajax calls to third party sites (that cause long delays).